# Loading custom map icons that relate to data in an XML table - Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I would like to display my own custom markers on a Google Map that is displaying data from an XML table. The map functions correctly and displays default markers, but I cannot work out how to change the markers to correspond to the data types in my table.

I've been following the [Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)  tutorial and have tried to incorporate their code for custom marker icons into mine but I haven't been able to get it to work. There are several other questions on here that sort of deal with this but I haven't been able to apply the answers to my code.

I have the following code first:

```
var map;
var markers = [];
var infoWindow;
var locationSelect;
var customIcons = {
        CP: {icon: 'icons/country_park.png'},
        LNR: {icon: 'icons/lnr.png'},
        PG: {icon: 'icons/parks_gardens.png'},
        SAC: {icon: 'icons/sac.png'},
        VG: {icon: 'icons/village_green.png'},
        WALK: {icon: 'icons/walk.png'},
        MG: {icon: 'icons/m_green.png'},
        MBC: {icon: 'icons/mbc.png'},
        WT: {icon: 'icons/wt.png'},
        KWT: {icon: 'icons/kwt.png'}        
    };
```

then this is the section that loads the positions from the XML:

```
var searchUrl = 'TESTxml_output.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
 downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
    var xml = parseXml(data);
    var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
        var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
        var agency = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("agency");
        var type = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("type");
        var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
            parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng"))
            );
        createOption(name, distance, i);
        createMarker(latlng, name, agency);
        bounds.extend(latlng);
        }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    locationSelect.style.visibility = "invisible";
    locationSelect.onchange = function() {
        var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
        };
    });
}

function createMarker(latlng, name, agency, type) {
    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + agency;    
    var icon = customIcons[type];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng,
        icon: icon
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    markers.push(marker);
    }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `createMarker` function takes 4 arguments, you are only providing 3 when you call it.

definition:

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, agency, type) {
```

call:

```
createMarker(latlng, name, agency);
```